# Updating one variable , updates the other variable

Tags: c#-4.0, ravendb

when i load to variable with the same data and update one of then the other gets updated to , Just curious why this happening and i am completely new to this and i just stared learning :)

```
using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
{
    var Example1 = session.Load<EX1>(string.Format("EX1/{0}", 11));
    var Example2 =session.Load<EX1>(string.Format("EX1/{0}", 11));
    Example1.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    Example1.CreatedBy = "Anand";
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

When i check the Example2 values it has been updated with same values of Example1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loaded `Example2`, RavenDB was smart enough to see that you've already loaded the same document in this session. Therefore it returned the same instance.

Comment: Sessions in asp.net are passed by reference, so I guess ravenDb does the same. In which case `example1` & `example2` would point to the same object

Comment: Thank you Thomas Freudenberg and @Serv